# Sencha Touch: do something when view store is ready

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a navigation view called "MenuPanel" as you see below.

Each "Child" record has a menu, if there is more than one child, I want to directly go to the existing child menu, otherwise I want to show children list view ('childlist' xtype).

Once the view is initialized there are 2 options (FIX me if I am wrong):

1. Store is loaded
2. Store is not loaded yet

I handle them using isLoaded() function and then add on('load') in case it is not loaded. However, I believe there is a better way to do it, maybe this should not be on initialize function.

Any ideas about best practices?

MenuPanel.js

```
Ext.define('eMaliApp.view.MenuPanel', {

    extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',

    xtype: 'menupanel',

    requires: [
        'eMaliApp.view.child.List',
        'eMaliApp.view.shared.TodayMenu'
    ],

    config: {

        store: 'children'

    },

    initialize: function() {

        this.callParent(arguments);

        var store = Ext.getStore('children');

        var me = this;
        var onStoreReady = function() {
            var data = store.getData();
            console.log('store data:', data);
            console.log('me:', me);
            if (_.isEmpty(data) || data.items.length > 1) {

                console.log('load children list');
                // add view
                var centersList = {
                    title: 'Child List',
                    xtype: 'childlist',
                    store: 'children',
                    showMenu: true
                };
                me.add(centersList);

            } else {

                // today menu
                console.log('today menu');
            };
        }

        if (store.isLoaded()) {
            console.log('Store is loaded');
            onStoreReady();
        } else {
            console.log('Store is NOT loaded');
            store.on('load', onStoreReady);
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the child views in the `initialize` method of the navigation view. This is business logic not view logic.

The controller which pushes the navigation view onto the viewport should also load the store. When the store is ready the controller should push the child view onto the navigation view. This should not be done in the `onStoreReady` method directly.

```
Ext.define('Test.controller.MainCtrl', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            menuPanel: 'menupanel'
        }
    },

    start: function () {
        var menuPanel = Ext.create( 'Test.view.MenuPanel' );
        Ext.Viewport.add( menuPanel );

        var store = Test.getStore( 'children' );
        var me = this;
        store.load(function ( records, operation, success ) {
                if ( success ) {
                    me.onChildrenStoreLoaded( records );    
                } else {
                    // error handling
                }
            },
            me
        );
    },

    onChildrenStoreLoaded: function ( records) {
        var menuPanel = this.getMenuPanel();

        if ( records.lenght === 1 ) {
            console.log('today menu');
        } else {
            console.log('load children list');
            var centersList = {
                title: 'Child List',
                xtype: 'childlist',
                store: 'children',
                showMenu: true
            };
            menuPanel.push(centersList);
        }
    }
});
```

The `start` method is the entry point. It just creates the navigation view and adds it to the viewport. It also starts loading of the store.

The anonymous method provided to the `store.load` method will execute when the store loaded. It will be run in the context of the controller (due to the second parameter of the load method).
It only checks if the loading was successful or not and delegates accordingly.

`onChildrenStoreLoaded` will push the correct views to the navigation view.

If loading the store takes a while you could also mask the viewport and unmask it in the anonymous method.

Comment: what is "start"? i see no "start" method for Ext.App.Controller,i guess you mean "init", right?

Comment: No, I didn't. The start method is just an imaginary entry point for the example. I don't know how you set up your app. So if you use a controller for that than you should put the start code into its init method. Otherwise you could put it where you initialize your navigation view ( or somewhere else). This depends entirely on your app setup.